# Docker springboot + postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

i have a Little question/issue. I have one api created with springboot, and this little app use a postgress db, when I try to put in a docker the java application, I receive the next error:

> 2023-03-06 17:23:55,369 ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : BackendHikariPool - Exception during pool initialization.
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:331)
> at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:223)
> at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:402)
> at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
> at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:266)

I review all de logic and stuff, and i think is connection problem. The database is another image running in docker. From the local machine I can connect using localhost, or the IP assigned in the docker network, but from another docker image (java) when try to run, always receive that error

I review all de logic and stuff, and i think is connection problem. The database is another image running in docker. From the local machine I can connect using localhost, or the IP assigned in the docker network, but from another docker image (java) when try to run, always receive that error

Updated:

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim 
ADD target/fitness-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

Database and another services
docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:12-alpine'
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: myuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
      POSTGRES_DB: fitness
    volumes:
      - 'postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
  localstack:
    image: 'localstack/localstack:0.12.14'
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
    environment:
      - DEFAULT_REGION=eu-central-1
      - SERVICES=sqs
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - /tmp/localstack:/tmp/localstack
      - ./config/localstack/sqs/setup-local-env.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d/setup-local-env.sh

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  localstack_data:
```

Comment: Did you tried to put the image name of your DB instead of localhost? It should work between docker images

Comment: not work. I try with the name of image..

spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: off
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://materia_postgres_1:5432/materia

For get the name of image, i use "docker ps -a" and the last columns is the name. It's ok?

Comment: For similar questions, it's been useful to know the connection string, which parts are running in containers, and how you started the containers involved.  Please search for similar questions, though: basic database connectivity questions come up very often, and the database connection string will be different if both the application and database are running in containers.

Comment: Share your property file, please and the dockerfile.

Comment: I had update the message with dockerfile and docker-compose.yml content

Comment: @DavielSánchez Are you using the name of the _service_ in your jdbc connection string, which in this case is `postgres`?

Comment: in this case is ... nameofproject_postgres_1